# Is there a special name for primes $p = 2^n+1$ and what is the largest known to date?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

I'm reading a paper by Pohlig and Hellman on computing discrete logarithms, they use primes $p = 2^n+1$ as a simple special case to explain their algorithm. I'm curious, is there a special name for these primes and what's the largest known prime with this structure? In the paper they mentioned that $2^{16}+1$ is the largest known, but the paper is from 1978.

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat_number  It is a classic result that any prime of your sort must in fact be a Fermat Number.

Comment: The largest known such prime still is $$2^{16}+1=65537$$ The next possible prime of this form is already extremely large : $$2^{(2^{33})}+1$$ Many mathematicians believe that there are no primes of this form beyond $65537$

Comment: @Peter . Eisenstein, a contemporary of Gauss, conjectured that $1+2^{2^{2^n}}$ is always prime. The discovery of any "simple" formula that  gives a strictly increasing sequence of primes would be spectacular news to number theorists.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, these primes are Fermat primes. The [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat_number) states that

> If $2^k+1$ is prime and $k>0$ it can be shown that $k$ is a power of $2$

And also

> As of 2016, the only known Fermat primes are $F_0, F_1, F_2, F_3$ and $F_4$.

So the largest known is $2^{2^4}+1 = 65537$.

[This article](https://wstein.org/edu/2010/414/projects/tsang.pdf) [Tsang, 2010] might be interesting reading for you!

Answer (score 4):

Let $n$ be a positive integer, $n=ab$ say, with $1 \leqslant a < n$, $1 < b \leqslant n$, and $b$ odd, where apart from the trivial case $a=1$, we require $a$ to be even. We have that

$$u^{ab}+v^{ab}=(u^a+v^a)\sum_{k=1}^{b}(-1)^{k+1}u^{a(b-k)}v^{a(k-1)}$$
Let $u=2$, $v=1$, then divide to get
$$\frac{2^{ab}+1}{2^a+1}=\sum_{k=1}^{b} (-1)^{k+1}2^{a(b-k)}$$
Then since $(2^a+1)\mid(2^{ab}+1)$, where $(2^a+1)>1$, we must have $2^n+1$ composite. Hence if $2^n+1$ is prime, then $n$ must be a power of $2$. These are the Fermat primes of the form $F_n=2^{2^n}+1$ and of which $2^{2^4}+1 = 65537$ is the largest known. Here are the first six Fermat numbers, where at $F_5$ (factored by Euler in 1732) they turn composite (maybe with no primes after $F_4$ in the sequence!):
\begin{align*}
F_0&=2^{2^0}+1=3=p_{2}\\
F_1&=2^{2^1}+1=5=p_{3}\\
F_2&=2^{2^2}+1=17=p_{7}\\
F_3&=2^{2^3}+1=257=p_{55}\\
F_4&=2^{2^4}+1=65537=p_{6543}\\
F_5&=2^{2^5}+1=4294967297=641\cdot6700417=p_{116}\cdot p_{457523}\\
\end{align*}